Youtube Data API reject our Agent request and see our tool as bot
We are part of the Google Startups Program and are Building AI Tools and Agents.
One of our tool do some youtube api request but we regularly seems to end up seen as bot and not able to query anymore as it ask suddenly for a login. We don't really understand why this happen, the issue is mostly when the agent run on the VPS while we don't see it when we run it locally.
Any idea what can be the issue? How to avoid it and how to lift the "ban" when this happen?
Thank you in advance.

it might be as you are using the youtube API without Authenticating.
It will result into google rate limiting you and marking you as spam.
You can try using a toolkit like https://composio.dev/tools/youtube.
